# character encoding conversion jackson and spring boot

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, apache-httpcomponents, spring-cloud-feign

As I understand from RFC, JSON is always UTF-*.

I have Spring REST service which receives JSON data from client. But in my system everything downstream is ISO-8859-1. Including storing data in database.

How can I configure jackson so that request - response when created, always changes from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 when request is received and ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 while sending response.

**Update :**

To give clear idea about my issue.

1. Read file that is in ISO-8859-1.
2. Extract data and create JSON object in UTF-8 (using jackson)
3. Receive UTF-8 data and store in database (may be in UTF-8)
4. Send out this UTF-8 data out in another flat file in ISO-8859-1

Most data, though its in UTF-8, it contains only subset that is ISO-8859-1 (1 byte)

My question : I use Spring-boot-rest on server.

Feign - apache http client on client.

For step 2 , Is there a cleaner way of converting ISO-8859-1 data into UTF-8 so all data / any api called, data is converted properly into UTF-8

Secondly, for step 4 while creating file, if data stored in DB is UTF-8 , how to make sure it converts data correctly while sending out.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a misconception about where character encodings apply. In the environment you describe, one side is REST to Java, the other side is Java to database (and possibly other things that you call *downstream*).

**REST to Java**: The REST requests and responses are usually in UTF-8. In Java, you simply have instances of the Java *String* class. They hide the encoding they use internally (Starting with Java 10 they even use two different encodings.) But from the outside, they look like a string of characters or Unicode code points. Jackson takes care of the conversion between UTF-8 and Java *String* instances.

**Java to database**: Most database interfaces will also accept Java *String* instances. They will use some encoding when transferring the data to the database. But you don't need to care about it. The database takes care of it.

So the **short story** is: the problem doesn't exist. No character encoding configuration for Jackson is needed.

Character encodings might be relevant for you if you write data to a text file. But that's not related to Jackson.

Comment: just added exact use case to explain my situation. My code fails at step1 and I don't know whats best practice to handle Step 4. Also, I use Feign with apache http client.